# SQL Server stored procedure - C# PK - FK

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Quite new to SQL Server and just discovered the wonderful world of stored procedures - and it already gives me a headache. Came here for help.

**Scenario 1**: given a table, I wrote a stored procedure and call it in C# to populate the table. Everything works as expected.

[Country SQL table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82S5i.png)

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertRecord2]
    @countryname nvarchar(64),
AS
    INSERT INTO Country(CountryName)
    VALUES (@countryname)

    RETURN
```

Calling in C#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    readonly SqlConnection _connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=REXGBASQLP042;Initial Catalog=isg_cid;Integrated Security=True");

    _connection.Open();

    SqlCommand _command = _connection.CreateCommand();
    _command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    _command.CommandText = "InsertRecord2";

    _command.Parameters.Add("@countryname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = countryname.Text;

    _command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    _connection.Close();
}
```

**Scenario 2**: I want to create a SQL view now, consists of the previous `Country` table and another table, let's call it `City`. `CountryID`, which is the PK for the `Country` table, is a FK in the `City` table.

[SQL view looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzFBK.png)

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertRecord2]
    @countryname nvarchar(64),
    @cityname nvarchar(64)
AS
    INSERT INTO Country(CountryName)
    VALUES (@countryname)

    INSERT INTO City(CityName)
    VALUES (@cityname)

    RETURN
```

Calling in C#:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    readonly SqlConnection _connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=REXGBASQLP042;Initial Catalog=isg_cid;Integrated Security=True");

    _connection.Open();

    SqlCommand _command = _connection.CreateCommand();
    _command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    _command.CommandText = "InsertRecord2";

    _command.Parameters.Add("@countryname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = countryname.Text;
    _command.Parameters.Add("@cityname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cityname.Text;

    _command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    _connection.Close();
}
```

And here comes the problem. Clicking on the button, I see an exception:

> Additional information: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CountryID', table 'isg_cid.dbo.City'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Okay, that's pretty obvious - a PK cannot be NULL. But, when I tried to insert into `Country` table, I didn't have to specify the ID (auto increment, auto seed switched ON), so

1. why do I have to specify it this time? and
2. how could I do that?

I suppose it should be done in the stored procedure somehow and I bet this is quite simple to solve - for someone with great experience with SSMS. For me, it's a hassle to figure out what to do.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you give the create table scripts for both the tables

Comment: Return the ID from the Stored procedure 1 and set in the stored procedure 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the `CountryID` field from the `Country` table but the `CountryID` field from the `City` table that triggers the error message.
This is the Foreign Key that links a City with its Country and logically cannot be let without a value when you insert a new City.

So, a possible approach is to read the last IDENTITY value set for the Country table using [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) and use this value to set the CountryID in the City table.

You need to change the second SP with

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertRecord2]
@countryname nvarchar(64),
@cityname nvarchar(64)

AS

    INSERT INTO Country(CountryName) VALUES (@countryname)
    INSERT INTO City(CountryID, CityName)
    VALUES (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @cityname)
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. Copypasted your code but this it seems to have a syntax error. See picture here:

http://imgur.com/a/xM0Dz

EDIT: if I remove SELECT, it works perfectly fine. Thank you!